# generate series using break time

Tags: postgresql, generate-series

I have a table that store opening hour and closing hour

```
    CREATE TABLE public.open_hours
(
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  open_hour character varying(255),
  end_hour character varying(255),
  day character varying(255),
  CONSTRAINT pk_open_hour_id PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE public.open_hours
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

I have another table that sotre

```
CREATE TABLE public.break_hours
(
id bigint ,
start_time character varying(255),
end_time character varying(255),
open_hour_id bigint ,
CONSTRAINT break_hours_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
 CONSTRAINT fkinhl5x01pnn54nv15ol5ntxr5 FOREIGN KEY (open_hour_id )
  REFERENCES public.open_hours(id) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE public.break_hours
OWNER TO postgres;
```

I need to generate time series of 30 minutest interval based on break times.

For eg: if my open hours is 08:00 AM and end hour is 06:00 PM and my break time is 11:00 AM to 11:30 and another break time is 03:00 PM to 03:15 PM then i need to generate series from 08:00 AM to 11:00 AM and 11:30 AM to 03:00 PM and 03:15 to 06:00 PM.

sample data

```
open_hours
-----------
id              open_hours                  end_hour    day
 1              08:00 AM                    06:00 PM    Monday
```

break_hours

---

```
id        start_time   end_time   open_hour_id
 1        11:00 AM     11:30 AM    1
 2        03:00 PM     03:15 PM    1

Sample out put
--------------
08:00 AM
08:30 AM
09:00 AM
09:30 AM
10:00 AM
10:30 AM
11:30 AM
12:00 PM
12:30 PM
01:00 PM
01:30 PM
02:PM PM
02:30 PM
03:15 PM
03:45 PM
04:15 PM
04:45 PM
05:15 PM

Query used for generating series between open hours is
SELECT DISTINCT gs AS start_time,gs + interval '30min' as end_time 
                     FROM   generate_series( timestamp '2018-11-09 08:00 AM', timestamp '2018-11-09 06:00 PM', interval '30min' )gs 
                     ORDER BY start_time
```

Comment: How is your second table connected to the first one? The times and dates are texts in your 2nd table. How look their values? What do you mean with "30 minute intervals" - I don't see any 30min intervals in your example. Please add some sample data and expected output.

Comment: Where is the date in the open_hours?

Comment: @S-Man Thanks for your quick reply , I updated my question with more details.I am trying to generate a booking system.so i need to list the available slots of 30 minutes using break hours and start and end hour.

Comment: @S-Man In open hours i store the day of the week like Monday.tuesday etc. and date i am planning to pass it to a procedure as an input parameter.so based on the day of the date i will get the open hours details from open hours table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your table modelling should be cleaned. E.g. you should not store times as text types but as `time without time zone`.

---

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=3620560c5f84f3747f8c65f18583f929)

```
WITH hours AS (
    SELECT 
        oh.open_hour + '1970-01-01'::date as open_hour, 
        oh.end_hour + '1970-01-01'::date as end_hour, 
        bh.start_time + '1970-01-01'::date as break_start,
        bh.end_time + '1970-01-01'::date as break_end,
        lead(start_time + '1970-01-01'::date) OVER (ORDER BY start_time) as next_start_time
    FROM open_hours oh
    LEFT JOIN break_hours bh
    ON oh.id = bh.start_date
)
SELECT generate_series(open_hour, break_start, interval '30 minutes')::time as time_slot 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        open_hour, break_start
    FROM hours
    ORDER BY break_start
    LIMIT 1
)s

UNION 

SELECT 
    generate_series(break_end, next_start_time, interval '30 minutes')::time
FROM ( 
    SELECT 
        break_end, next_start_time
    FROM
        hours
    WHERE next_start_time IS NOT NULL
) s

UNION

SELECT generate_series(break_end, end_hour, interval '30 minutes')::time 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        break_end, end_hour
    FROM hours
    ORDER BY break_start DESC
    LIMIT 1
) s
```

**Explanation**:

**`WITH` clause (CTE):**

Merging both tables. I am adding a nonsense date because this results in a `timestamp`. The later used function `generate_series` only works for `timestamp`s not for type `time`. The part is cut away later after the generation with the `::time` cast.

The result of the CTE is:

```
open_hour             end_hour              break_start           break_end             next_start_time
1970-01-01 08:00:00   1970-01-01 18:00:00   1970-01-01 09:30:00   1970-01-01 09:45:00   1970-01-01 11:00:00
1970-01-01 08:00:00   1970-01-01 18:00:00   1970-01-01 11:00:00   1970-01-01 11:30:00   1970-01-01 15:00:00
1970-01-01 08:00:00   1970-01-01 18:00:00   1970-01-01 15:00:00   1970-01-01 15:15:00   (NULL)
```

**`UNION` part:**

This part contains three subparts. Because I have to merge the time series from both tables:

**1.** Taking the opening hour. Generate a time series to the first break beginning.

For this I only need the first row from the CTE above. That's why `LIMIT 1` is used.

**2.** For *all* breaks: Generate a time series from current break ending to the next break beginning.

The CTE contains a [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) `lead()` which shifts the `start_time` of the next row into the current one (have a look at the last column of the CTE result). So now I am able to get all break times, no matter how many there are. In my example I added a third break from `9:30` to `9:45` to demonstrate it. So the next time series can be generated from all these columns (current `break_end` to `next_start_time`). Only the last row does not contain a `next_start_time` because there is none.

**3.** Last step: Generate a time series from the last break ending to the closing hour.

This is quiet similar to (1). After iterating all break times I have to add the last time series from the last break time to the closing time. This could be achieved either by filtering the row without `next_start_time` or sorting `DESC` and using `LIMIT 1` as I did.

---

*More complex case with more day types:*

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=62115df0c5e6b7f704b503220a87a269)

```
WITH hours AS (
    SELECT 
        oh.id as day_id,
        oh.open_hour + '1970-01-01'::date as open_hour, 
        oh.end_hour + '1970-01-01'::date as end_hour, 
        bh.start_time + '1970-01-01'::date as break_start,
        bh.end_time + '1970-01-01'::date as break_end,
        lead(start_time + '1970-01-01'::date) OVER (PARTITION BY oh.id ORDER BY start_time) as next_start_time
    FROM open_hours oh
    LEFT JOIN break_hours bh
    ON oh.id = bh.start_date
)

SELECT day_id, generate_series(open_hour, break_start, interval '30 minutes')::time as time_slot 
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (day_id)
        day_id, open_hour, break_start
    FROM hours
    ORDER BY day_id, break_start
)s

UNION 

SELECT 
    day_id, generate_series(break_end, next_start_time, interval '30 minutes')::time
FROM ( 
    SELECT  
        day_id, break_end, next_start_time
    FROM
        hours
    WHERE next_start_time IS NOT NULL
) s

UNION

SELECT day_id, generate_series(break_end, end_hour, interval '30 minutes')::time 
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (day_id)
        day_id, break_end, end_hour
    FROM hours
    ORDER BY day_id, break_start DESC
) s

ORDER BY day_id, time_slot
```

The main idea stays the same as in the example for only one day. The difference is that we have to consider the different day types. I expanded the example above and added a second day with different opening hours and break times.

**Changes:**

1. The window function in the CTE got a `PARTITION BY` part. This ensures that only the `start_time`s are shifted that contains to the same day.
2. `LIMIT 1` will not work anymore because it limits the whole table to one row. This has been changed to `DISTINCT ON (day_id)` which limits the table to the first row of each day.

Comment: Thanks for the answer .but i need a general solution if I am having multiple break time i need to add more union right?

Comment: Changed the answer, expanded it to many days, added explanations

Comment: Thanks for the correct answer. I was looking for the same solution.